# PHP mailgun mailer issue

Tags: php, mailgun, mailer

New at PHP and trying to integrate mailgun to send to multiple forms. Below is the code for my PHP script which is using mailgun.

When sending the email using a simple mailgun script i am able to receive email but when i attach it to the forms i don't get any email.

```
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
use Mailgun\Mailgun;

else if($_GET['method'] == 'send_form'){

    $to = 'myemail@email.com';
    $message = 'Name : '.$_POST['name'].'<br />';
    $message .= 'Mobile : '.$_POST['mobile'].'<br />';
    $message .= 'Email : '.$_POST['email'].'<br />';
    $from = $name.' <'.$from.'>';
    $name = $_POST['name'];

    $subject = 'Email Subj for form 1';

    $headers =  "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=iso-8859-1" . "\r\n";
    $headers .= 'From: '.$name.' <'.$from.'>' . "\r\n";

    send_mail($to,$from,$subject,$message);
}

else if($_GET['method'] == 'send_form_two'){

    $to = 'myemail@email.com';
    $message = 'Name : '.$_POST['name'].'<br />';
    $message .= 'Mobile : '.$_POST['mobile'].'<br />';
    $message .= 'Email : '.$_POST['email'].'<br />';
    $from = $name.' <'.$from.'>';
    $name = $_POST['name'];

    $subject = 'Email subject for form 2';

    $headers =  "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=iso-8859-1" . "\r\n";
    $headers .= 'From: '.$name.' <'.$from.'>' . "\r\n";

    send_mail($to,$from,$subject,$message);


}


function send_mail($to, $from, $subject,$content)
{

    $mgClient = new Mailgun('mailgunkey-here');
    $domain = "mg.domain.com";

    $result = $mgClient->sendMessage($domain, array(
        'from'    => $from,
        'to'      => $to,
        'subject' => $subject,
        'text'    => $content
    ));
}
```

Seems like my code does not want 'from' => $from,

changing the from to static email resulted to sent mails.

Comment: Are you getting any error?

Comment: i don't because i redirect the page on send

               $.post(base_url+'ajax/functions.php?method=send_form',$("form#nozipform").serialize(),function(data){
              window.location = 'http://domain.com/successmail.php';
          });

Comment: Some code seems to be missing here, there is no initial IF statement.